# GPG encryption using shell_exec not working with the browser but works with the terminal

Tags: php, gnupg

Here's my code that I'm running on a browser. It will encrypt the file and the output will be in different path. I can run it with the terminal but doesn't work on browser. Somebody said that I should check my web configuration but I'm confuse with it. Thanks in advance! =)

```
<?php
    echo 1;

    shell_exec ("gpg --output /home/datafeeding/testing/sampledick.xls.gpg --encrypt --recipient rtalplacido@yahoo.com /opt/jasperserver-3.5.0/apache-tomcat/webapps/JavaBridge/reports/sampledick.xls");

    echo 2;
    echo "<br>";

?>
```

Comment: When you say, doesn't work, what do you mean exactly? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

you're better off using the gnupg extension for php

Answer (score 0):

Adding **`--batch`** to your `gpg` command-line will probably take care of it, but you should probably also add **`--no-tty`** (and **`--yes`** if you want it to overwrite files).

The `gpg` man page has the details, but that should cover it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with coding in php, but what is it doing with stderr? No errors at all? Maybe you don't have rights to write the output file. Could be a permissions issue (maybe even SELinux).

Comment: yes, that's what I'm also thinking. no permission to execute gpg for www-data user.

Comment: Also, you might need to specify the gpg home directory (where the keys are stored) using the `--homedir` option, and make sure that location can be read by the account executing this command. And **write** access to the output location of course.